# Find most frequently used query

Tags: sql, database, oracle, statistics

I am trying to find the most used query in an oracle database.. Im a little confused! Are these types of statistics stored in the AWR table? If so how would I use this table to find the most popular query executed on the database? Thanks!

Comment: more of a dba question, but do you have access to OEM?  Should be a top-SQL report there

Comment: I don't have access to OEM unfortunately! But will look into it thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT ADDRESS, SQL_TEXT, PARSE_CALLS, EXECUTIONS
FROM V$SQLAREA
ORDER BY EXECUTIONS desc;
```

Comment: Cheers for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

That might be fast on many systems one system I was on last week took > 3 minutes to execute a query like this. To make it more efficient, it's cheaper to select from v$sqlstats. thatn v$sqlarea. Also since you are doing an order by you might want to limit the rows sorted with something like "executions > X"

select * from  (
SELECT  SQL_ID, SQL_TEXT, PARSE_CALLS, EXECUTIONS
FROM   v$sqlstats
where executions > 10
ORDER BY EXECUTIONS desc
) where rownum < 10;

Answer (score 1):

we can identify excution count in AWR report also.

[image]